# ARM Architecture and programming model of it

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

I'm software engineer student and i need some easy-understanding and reliable articles or any explanation about "Programmers model in ARM Processors" and "ARM Processors Architecture" for my Computer Architecture university course......
can any one help me on this..?
thanks all...

Comment: Search for "ARM Architecture Reference Manual PDF" in Google" and start from there

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com, along the left side look for architecture, and expand that to find the family, the armv5 manual is what used to be the single ARM ARM (ARM Architectural Reference Manual) now they split it up, should probaby get that one and the core you are using.  Also go down and get the TRM, technical reference manual for the specific core, the ARM ARM is generic to the family, the TRM tells you exactly what from the ARM ARM you have and do not have for this core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply go to [infocenter.arm.com](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp), ARM's documentation root. There you'll find any number of documents about their architecture.

Comment: tnx every one...good links...but i need something more closer to "programmers model" rather than "Architecture" ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the [ARM System Developer's Guide.](http://books.google.com/books/about/Arm_System_Developer_s_Guide.html?id=HKKUkDQE17QC).  Despite what that link says, there is an eBook and I think it is what you want.